# Homekit: multi mode button in home app

Tags: homekit

Is anyone aware of a HomeKit enabled device which exposes a control element/button in the Home app which allows you to cycle through modes (each click changes a "mode" - whatever mode means for the particular device)? I'm trying to find out whether this kind of button/control exists in HomeKit/Home app to build a device that exposes such a button.

**Edit**

Here is what I am referring to. The image shows 2 controls (a slider and a switch). I require the switch to have more than two states. Does anyone know if there is a device that exposes such a behaviour to Homekit?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  You might need to make this narrower. Ask on a DIY or hardware site and once you have a working kit, then refine here. I could see a general, how can I tell if hardware X works with HomeKit being open here for answers if you don’t have a start yet on which hardware you will choose to work with.

Comment: Ok, I refined the question. Please check, comment and possibly re-open it. I'm faced with kind of a chicken egg problem here. I don't know how the hardware should behave in order for it to appear in Home.

Comment: thanks for sending me in the right direction with your review.

Comment: The only think I know is open source homebridge but then you can do anything - raspberry pi and arduino have relays and all sorts of interfaces. https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-2-Homekit-from-zero-to-Hey-Siri/ Maybe you’re looking for a commercial product?

Comment: A homebridge example would be great as their configuration is mimicking an actual HomeKit device. I just need to know the configuration (or an actual device) which exposes such a button (so I know which kind of service/characteristic etc to implement in my custom device).

Comment: I added a screenshot to explain better what I am referring to.

Comment: Hi Orange - So the question is how to change the right gray button from on/off to on/low/high for instance?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The question is whether the Homekit app (or Homekit in general) even allows for that sort of button (an existing device which exposes such a button would confirm that). And if the Homekit app doesn't allow for it, are there other apps (3rd party homekit apps) that do?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but here's a list of all accessory service types supported in Apple HomeKit. This defines the entire scope of possibilities in the Home app.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmservice/accessory_service_types

The accessory categories are:

- Light
- Power and Switches
- Air Quality and Smoke Detection
- Temperature and Humidity
- Windows
- Water
- Locks and Openers
- Safety and Security
- Video and Audio
- Information

However, I am not familiar enough with the HomeKit ADK to fully answer your question.

Comment: Is any of these accessories appearing as a multi state switch in the Home App?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, custom modes in smart home applications are simply linked to the slider position of the fan speed or light brightness, which are then mapped to discrete values for different modes. For instance, you might use a range of 0-10 for mode 1, 11-20 for mode 2, and so on.

As an example, consider a custom vacuum robot plugin in a HomeKit environment. It can utilize a fan accessory where the fan speed slider at zero typically means to turn the vacuum off and instruct the robot to return to its charging station. When the slider is set to 100%, it might activate turbo mode, while 10% could represent a silent mode, and so forth. This mapping of slider positions to different modes provides users with a user-friendly way to control and customize the device's behavior.

Additionally, many smart devices allow you to combine multiple accessory characteristics into a single device, as shown in your screenshot.